# Yes/No with for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I made yes/no prompt with case and if but couldn't make it with for loop. How can I do that with for loop?

**IF**

```
if [ "$ANS" = "Yes" -o "$ANS" = "yes" -o "$ANS" = "y" -o "$ANS" = "Y" ] ; then 
ANS="y" 
else 
ANS="n" 
fi 
echo $ANS
```

**CASE**

```
case "$ANS" in 
      [Yy]|[Yy][Ee][Ss]) ANS="y" ;; 
      *) ANS="n" ;; 
esac
```

Comment: `for answer in Yes yes y Y; do [[ $answer == $ANS ]]; do :; done`

Comment: What do you exactly mean with a for loop? What do you want to do that if and case statements don't?

Comment: @nino I want for loop to do the exactly same thing what if and case does.

Comment: a `loop` iterates over members of a list/array while `if` and `case` statements here are checking conditions. They are two different things.

Comment: Yeah, I know if and case are statements. I just wanted to know if it's possible to do the same thing with for.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a while loop that exits only if the answer is yes, y, etc.

```
while ! [ "$ANS" = "Yes" -o "$ANS" = "yes" -o "$ANS" = "y" -o "$ANS" = "Y" ] ; do
    echo "Give a positive reply..."
    read ANS
done

echo $ANS
```

Comment: I think this is best option, i do not know if `for v *not in* values` even exists.

Comment: I do not know either

Comment: Alternatively with a regex: `while ! [[ "$ANS" =~ ^(Yes|yes|y|Y)$ ]]; do`